# Points $z\in \mathbb{C}/L$ such that $\Phi(z)\in E(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, elliptic-curves

Consider the isomorphism $\Phi:\mathbb{C}/L\rightarrow E/\mathbb{C}$ given by $z\mapsto (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ (when $z\not\in L$, and $z\mapsto 0$ if $z\in L$). In particular,

$$\wp(z)=\sum_{l\in L^\times} \frac{1}{(z-l)^2}-\frac{1}{l^2}$$

Are there any known results on (algorithms for?) finding which *specific* complex points $z$ satisfy $\Phi(z)\in E(\mathbb{Q})$? That is, can we classify explicitly which (/examples of) $z\in \mathbb{C}/L$ map to rational points of the elliptic curve?

Is this straightforward and if not is there literature on it? One can substitute $\mathbb{Q}$ for some extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}]$ and similarly ask when $\Phi(z)\in E(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}])$.

Comment: How will you distinguish between rational points of $y^2=x^3+3$ and $-y^2=x^3+3$ on the complex torus side?

Comment: @reuns If we fix an (($\wp(x),\wp'(x)$)) isomorphism $\Phi$ to a curve, say $\Phi: \mathbb{C}/L\rightarrow E_+/\mathbb{C}$ where $E_+: y^2=x^3+3$, then we can ask what the rational points on the complex torus side are with respect to the specific curve ($E_+$). I don't mean to imply that the points are rational w.r.t to both $E_-: -y^2=x^3+3$ and $E_+$. Or am I misunderstanding what you are asking?

Comment: I am saying that the complex torus side doesn't help at all for Mordell theorem, as evident when comparing the complex tori associated to the different twists of $E$. Did you take a look at Silverman's book AEC?

Comment: @reuns I may have stated my question loosely and will edit: I am not interested in general about the group $E(\mathbb{Q})$, but rather which specific complex points $z$ map under $\Phi$ to $E(\mathbb{Q})$: Can we classify/find these points algorithmically? I understand Mordell's theorem states that $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Again the complex torus side doesn't help. Finding non-torsion points is hard, take a look at Silverman's book. https://mathoverflow.net/a/151206/84768